# Hibernate/JPA/Spring Problems with persisting (sorted) collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Originally I wanted to write this as a question, but upon writing this post, I found a solution. If someone here got a better one, since mine is a bit ugly, feel free to post it. Otherwise I will just archive my solution here so that other people facing a similar problem will know. (Solution can be found at the bottom.)

I have the following demands which need to be met:

- Display all "modules" with Checkboxes on the webpage
- Sort the modules by two subsets of each other:

  1. Subset to be displayed at the top: All the modules that are selected and thus held inside the "modules" collection on the Information-Entity
  2. Subset to be displayed beneath: All the modules that haven't been selected yet (with ID>0) and are retrieved from the database directly
- Sort each of these subsets alphabetically (case insensitive)

The result should look like this:

```
[x] aaaModule
[x] AbbModule
[x] aBcModule
[ ] aabModule
[ ] acbModule
```

Note that the sorting needs to be case insensitive, which is why @OrderBy doesn't cut it. Instead I went with implementing the Comparable interface to the Entity-Class to be sorted and used the @SortNatural-Annotation of Hibernate on the @ManyToMany mapping.

My current solution (simplified of course) looks as follows:

Inside the Information.java Entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "bla_modules", 
    schema = "blaSchema",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bla_info_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bla_module_id") }
)
@SortNatural
private Set<Module> modules = new TreeSet<>();
```

Inside the Controller.java (in the GET-Mapping):

```
Set<Module> modulesToDisplay = new LinkedHashSet<>();
modulesToDisplay.addAll(currentInformation.getModules());
modulesToDisplay.addAll(moduleRepository.findByIdGreaterThanOrderByLabelAsc(0));
model.addAttribute("modulesToDisplay", modulesToDisplay);
```

Inside the information.jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/informations.bla/editInformation" modelAttribute="currentInformation">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <c:forEach items="${modulesToDisplay}" var="module">
            <li>
                <div class="inline">
                    <form:checkbox path="modules" value="${module}" label="[${module.shortLabel}] ${module.label}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form:form>
```

Inside the Controller.java (the POST-Mapping):

```
public String editInformation(@ModelAttribute Information submittedInformation) {
    Information informationAfterSaving = informationRepository.save(submittedInformation);
```

It all worked great prior to me having the @SortNatural annotation on the collection, but in that case JPA didn't sort the TreeSet when loading it from the database.

It also still works great, if I load an existing Information-Entity from the database, display that, change attributes, and then save it back.

However, when I load a new Information-Entity, which just got created in the Controller via "new Information()", when the GET-Mapping doesn't receive a valid ID to load, then I suddenly get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashSet cannot be cast to class java.util.SortedSet` when the `Information informationAfterSaving = informationRepository.save(submittedInformation);` inside the POST-Mapping of the Controller is executed.

The solution can be found in my own answer below. I hope it might help someone someday.

Bye

Comment: As a quick favor, can you format this in a Q&A format (i.e. state the problem as a question and the solution as an answer)? That would make it easier for future readers who are facing similar problems.

Comment: Most likely I would have just sorted it in the GUI :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica How exactly do you envision that? I currently can't think of a way to properly state the problem/requirements I've had as a question, to be honest, since it's a bit technical and requires a lot of detail. It's not just "How do I sort a Set", but "How can I have a sorted set with <all these qualities I listed over the entirety of my problem statement> that can be retrieved and stored via JPA?" If I were to put that into a question it would be quite a long question indeed. :/

Comment: @MartinFrey Thanks for that possible solution. :) Certainly makes sense. I don't really think this would suit my specific use-case though. (We already have too much of a JavaScript clusterfuck running on the respective page either way. Q_Q)

Comment: Suggestion: Can you (a) remove the answer text from your question, and instead post it as an answer (where it says "Your Answer" below), and also (b) remove the `(SOLVED) ` text from the question's title? You are welcome on SO to answer your own question, if you think the question and answer will be useful to someone else in the future. You can even accept your own answer. (I think this is essentially what EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica was saying.)

Comment: Well, how do you describe it now? Does your current post give people enough information to understand the context for the solution? If so, that's good enough for a question. If not, adding more detail would definitely make the solution easier to understand.

Comment: @andrewjames Ah okay. :) I did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

Inside the POST-Mapping of the Controller prior to calling the .save method of the Repository, just do the following:

```
submittedInformation.setModules(new TreeSet<Module>(submittedInformation.getModules()));
```

I feel a bit stupid now that I didn't think of this obvious solution earlier, not gonna lie.

The solution is still a bit ugly though, so if someone knows how to tell JPA/Hibernate to properly convert the received collection from Spring back into a TreeSet, or to tell Spring to attach the Checkbox-Collection in the form of a TreeSet, then please tell me.

### Alternative

Not a suitable solution for me, but @MartinFrey also gave a possible solution: Just skip the sorting on the backend side and instead sort on the GUI side.